# listings incorrectly highlights PHP keywords

Tags: listings

I have definitions as below:

```latex
\lstset{
    commentstyle = \color{gray},
    extendedchars = \true,
    inputencoding = utf8x,
    language = php,
    keepspaces = true,
    keywordstyle = \bfseries
}
```

And here's the code:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP]
        function processRequest()
        {
            $req = $this->request;
            $view = $this->view;
            $view->addHeaderScript("scripts/jquery_addons.js");
            // doing smth...
            return $this->view;
        }
```

But only `if`, `else` and `foreach` keywords are highlighted. I want `function` and `return` keywords also to be highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function` and `return` seem not to be in the PHP keyword default list (which can be found in the file `lstdrvrs`); you can add them using `morekeywords`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=PHP,
    commentstyle = \color{gray},
    extendedchars = \true,
    inputencoding = utf8x,
    keepspaces = true,
    keywordstyle = \bfseries,
    morekeywords={function,return}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
        function processRequest()
        {
            $req = $this->request;
            $view = $this->view;
            $view->addHeaderScript("scripts/jquery_addons.js");
            // doing smth...
            return $this->view;
        }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]